# Only one Looper may be created per thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app which request data information on internet (client-server app), but this communication is very slow, thus i have decided to create an AsyncTask to manage the delay.
inside of doInBackground i call `Looper.prepare()` then a my "view generator (which retrives data)".

**in detail (the problem):**

I have an activity that dinamically create the rows of a list view. but every time i try to inflate rows, android throws  a Looper exception "Only one Looper may be created per thread"

i followed the steps:

- call `Looper.preapare()`
- use a first inflaction to create a container of my list
- use a second inflaction to create a list row

I suppose I cannot inflate two times but i don't know how i can resolve that

**AsyncTask**

```
private class DrawerView extends AsyncTask<ActivityGroup, String, View>{
    Exception exc=null;     

    @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();   
}

@Override protected View doInBackground(ActivityGroup... params) {
    try {
        Looper.prepare();
    return processAct();
    }catch (ConnectionException e) {    
        exc =e;
    return null;                
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        exc = e;
    return null;
    }
}

@Override protected void onPostExecute(View result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(exc!= null){
        Utils.usrMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Oh Noo!:\n"+exc.getMessage());
        Utils.logErr(getApplicationContext(), exc);
    finish();
    }
    if(result!= null){
        setContentView(result);
    }
}
}
```

`processAct()` is an abstract method implemented in this way

```
@Override protected View processAct() throws Exception {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    User user = (User)bundle.getSerializable("user");

    Team team =  Team.getTeamInformation(this,user.getTeamId());
    ArrayList<Player> players =Player.getPlayerList(this,user.getTeamId());

    PlayersListAdapter view = new PlayersListAdapter(this,players,team);
    return view;
}
```

`PlayerListAdapter` is the class which builds/sets first view (list container)..here the first inflation

```
public PlayersListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players,Team team) throws Exception{
    super(context);
    View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.team_players, this);

    TextView tv_teamName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tbplrs_tmnm);
    TextView tv_playersNum = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tbplrs_nplrs);

    tv_teamName.setText(team.getName());

    String msg = players.size()+" ";
    msg += (players.size()!=1)?context.getString(R.string.playerPlural):context.getString(R.string.playerSingle);
    tv_playersNum.setText(msg);

    ListView lView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.tbplrs_plrslst);
    PlayersRowListAdapter plAdapter = new PlayersRowListAdapter(context, players);
    lView.setAdapter(plAdapter);
}
```

at last `PlayerRowListAdapter` which extends BaseAdapter,...here the second inflation

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater lInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = lInflator.inflate(R.layout.team_player_singlplayer,null);
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

N.B. if i drop the second adapter `PlayerRowListAdapter`...all works fine...(obviously without list)

Regards

p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: Code please, we don't know what you exactly did :)

Comment: i think you should, as chrulri said in his answer, retrieve the contents in doInBackground() and then inflate in onPostExecute() or in onProgressUpdate(). I#m wondering why it doesn't crash on the first inflate....

Comment: bha...i don't know....i have a lot "pages" in my application and only pages with list view (then, pages with two inflations) crash with this exception...however, i resolved that...; ), now post my solution...thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I worked around this.

As the [Developer Reference for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says,
`doInBackground` creates a new thread to manage it (this has forced me to call `Looper.prepare()`), while `onPostExecute()` uses the main thread.

So I sliced `processAct()` in two methods: `prepareData()` which retrieves data and `createView()` which calls adapter.

I have put the first method into `doInBackground()`, and the second one (`createView()`) I have put into `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of just calling `Looper.prepare();`, first check if Looper does not already exist for your Thread, if not, call that function. Like this:

```
if (Looper.myLooper()==null)
    Looper.prepare();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you need to call `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` is when you want to have a message `Handler` in a thread that is not the UI thread.  Basically, it keeps the thread alive forever so that the `Handler` that was created inside the thread can still send and receive messages.  The same goes for callback methods like `LocationListener` or something similar.  You are responsible for killing the thread when it is done by calling `Looper.getMyLooper().quit()` inside the thread that it is in.

If you are inflating views in the UI thread, then you do not need to call `Looper.prepare()` or `Looper.loop()` as this is already done in the background.  You should never inflate `Views` outside the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask already has its own `Looper`. If you want to update your UI from your `doInBackground()` method use [`publishProgress(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) which then invokes [`onProgressUpdate(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) in the main thread. In your `onProgressUpdate` you can inflate your Views and add them to your UI.

Edit: example code: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html